# Toshiba p55w turn on, but aproximately after 1 hour show bios

Tags: toshiba-laptop, laptop-repair

Best regards, I hope you can help me. my problem is that I have a toshiba p55w which turns on but for more than an hour or so it does not show anything, after that starts the bios and the operating system, the truth try to find how to reset the bios, believing that is the problem, but that laptop does not come with a battery anymore, and it does not indicate anything about CMOS, any idea can help me

Comment: It has a bios battery, it may not be easily accessible. I can find no service manual for it ether.

Comment: BIOS batteries do eventually need replacement, and yours could, but these symptoms don't sound like they are caused by a bad battery.  I also wouldn't assume the BIOS needs to be reset.  If you can easily do those things, it will rule them out, but it could be other hardware problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to get more information before you can actually troubleshoot.

I would start by looking at the logs, depending on your OS version, it could point some light into the issue. The fact that it runs for an hour, would make me look into heating and memory issues first.

Both can be tested using various software. Outside of heat and memory, power would be the next check before reloading the OS itself. If you are still running into issues, and you reload the BIOS, it's most likely a damaged motherboard.

For reloading the BIOS:
https://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=4006854